# How to display fieldset text and button inline on small screens?

Tags: html, css

First of all, sorry for my bad English.

I would like to display a fieldset **input text** and **input submit** inline.
The button should have a fixed width, based on the font-size and the text-field should fill up the rest of the space on the same line.

I have the following fieldset and CSS:

```css
.example {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.example fieldset {
  font-size: 1.05em;
  border: 0px;
  background-color: #c3dedb;
  padding: 10px;
}
.example fieldset input[type="text"] {
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
  font-size: inherit;
  border: 0px;
}
.example fieldset input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #1a7a70;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: inherit;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
}
.example fieldset input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #187269;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="p" value="0,00">
      <input type="submit" value="Nu bieden">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

With this code the following happens width bigger screens:

[image: http://oi62.tinypic.com/vwrdb4.jpg]

And the following with small screens:

[image: http://oi58.tinypic.com/x5a04w.jpg]

**My question**

How can I get the input field and the button always inline, even with smaller screens? And how can I give the input field fill up the rest of the space on the same line? I tried to give it 100% width, but then the button jumps to the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid text wrapping setting [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to `pre` or `nowrap`:

```css
.example fieldset {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```css
.example {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.example fieldset {
  font-size: 1.05em;
  border: 0px;
  background-color: #c3dedb;
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.example fieldset input[type="text"] {
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
  font-size: inherit;
  border: 0px;
}
.example fieldset input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #1a7a70;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: inherit;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
}
.example fieldset input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #187269;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="p" value="0">
      <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

And to make it fill all the remaining space, you can add a wrapper and reorder the inputs:

```html
<input type="submit" value="Go">
<div><input type="text" name="p" value="0"></div>
```

With those styles:

```css
.example fieldset div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.example fieldset input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
}
.example fieldset input[type="submit"] {
    float: right;
}
```

```css
.example {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.example fieldset {
  font-size: 1.05em;
  border: 0px;
  background-color: #c3dedb;
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.example fieldset div {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.example fieldset input[type="text"] {
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
  font-size: inherit;
  border: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
.example fieldset input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #1a7a70;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: inherit;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  float: right;
}
.example fieldset input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #187269;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="submit" value="Go">
      <div><input type="text" name="p" value="0"></div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This displays them inline, but the input field doesn't resize. It should exactly fit in the current screen size.